# One normal mode frequency not seen in Resonance in forced coupled oscilators

Tags: classical-mechanics, resonance, normal-modes

The problem is that I have three charges with mass $m$ connected by two springs with the same elastic constant. The first and the last charge has charge $q$, the middle one $-q$. They are inside an electric field, $E_0 \exp(i\omega t)$. I can ignore the interaction of the charges, so I have to take into account the force $qE$.

I have solved the problem, finding that the second normal mode is not a resonance but I'm asked the physics meaning of it, and I'm not really sure.
While transforming to normal coordinate, the electric force dissapear in this equation but I'm not sure about what does it mean in physics term. Maybe is that as the autovector of this normal mode is the first mass in antiphase with the last one, while the middle one stay static. Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Center of mass motion?

Comment: The center of mass motion normal mode is usually associated with the normal mode w=0, isn't it? which is a resonance frequency. And why the center of mass motion normal modr should not be a resonance mode?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your normal modes refer to the system in the absence of the external time-dependent force (i.e. $E_0=0$). What I wanted to say was simply, that one of these normal modes should be the COM coordinate  $x$, with the EOM $3 m \ddot{x} = (2q-q) E_0 \exp(i \omega t)$ (independent of the elastic constants = internal forces) once the external force is switched on. I just wanted to make sure that you have identified this trivial solution as a check of your calculation.

Comment: Yes I've obtained this normal mode, which correspond to 0 frequency, but it also appears as a resonance frequency

Answer (score 0):

Denoting the the coordinates of the three mass points by $x_1$ (charge $+q$), $x_2$ (charge $-q$) and $x_3$ (charge $+q$), the equations of motion are given by $$\begin{align}\ddot{x}_1 &= -\omega_0^2 (x_1-x_2)+qE(t)/m, \\ \ddot{x}_2 &=- \omega_0^2 (2x_2-x_1-x_3)-qE(t)/m, \\ \ddot{x}_3 &= -\omega_0^2 (x_3-x_2) + qE(t)/m, \end{align}$$ with a time-dependent electric field $E(t)=E_0 e^{i\omega t}$. A glance at this system of coupled differential equations reveals that the the normal modes of the unperturbed system are characterized by the combinations $x_1+x_2+x_3$ (center of mass (COM) motion, eigenfrequency $0$), $x_1-x_3$ (eigenfrequency $\omega_0$) and $x_1-2x_2+x_3$ (eigenfrequeny $\sqrt{3} \, \omega_0$) with the corresponding decoupled equations of motion $$\begin{align} \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left( x_1(t)+x_2(t)+x_3(t)  \right)  &=2qE(t)/m, \\ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \left(x_1(t)-x_3(t)\right) &=-\omega_0^2 (x_1-x_3), \\ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \left(x_1(t)-2x_2(t)+x_3(t) \right)&=-3\omega_0^2 (x_1-2x_2+x_3)+4qE(t)/m.   \end{align}$$ As the charges and the masses of the particles $1$ and $3$ are the same, it is thus no surprise that the external forces cancel for the normal mode $x_1-x_3$, in accordance with your findings. The general solution for the three normal modes is given by $$\begin{align} x_1(t) +x_2(t)+x_3(t) &= u t + s -\frac{2qE_0 e^{i\omega t}}{m\omega^2} \\
x_1(t)-x_3(t) &= A \cos \omega_0 t + B\sin \omega_0 t \\ x_1(t)-2 x_2(t) + x_3(t) &= C \cos \sqrt{3}\omega_0 t + D \sin\sqrt{3}\omega_0 t-\frac{4qE_0e^{i \omega t}}{m \omega^2}. \end{align}$$ In the reference frame where $u=s=0$, the COM coordinate $x(t)=(x_1(t)+x_2(t)+x_3(t))/3$ oscillates around $x=0$ with the amplitude $|2qE_0/3 m \omega^2|$. Expressed in terms of the original coordinates $x_{1,2,3}$, the solution with $C=D=0$ corresponds to the situation where $$\begin{align} x_1(t) &=x(t)+\frac{1}{2}\left( A \cos \omega_0 t +B \sin \omega_0 t \right) -\frac{2qE_0 e^{i \omega t}}{3 m \omega^2}, \\ x_2(t) &= x(t) + \frac{4 q E_0 e^{i \omega t}}{3 m \omega^2}, \\x_3(t) &= x(t) - \frac{1}{2}(A \cos \omega_0t +B \sin \omega_0 t)-\frac{2 q E_0 e^{i \omega t}}{3 m \omega^2}    \end{align}, $$ leading to the following physical interpretion: Relative to the center of mass coordinate $x(t)$, particle $2$ oscillates with the external driving frequency $\omega$ and the amplitude $|4qE_0/3 m \omega^2|$. Again relative to the COM, the particles $1$ and $3$ oscillate in phase with frequency $\omega$ (but with a phase difference $\pi$ relative to particle $2$) with amplitude $|2qE_0/3 m \omega^2|$, superimposed by the oscillation $\pm \frac{1}{2} (A \cos \omega_0 t +B \sin \omega_0 t)$ with eigenfrequency $\omega_0$.